# Vue - Return back to callabck url after login complete using window.open

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a vue + laravel application. Here I have button called **Open Window Now**. Once I click on it it's showing a new window to **login with google**. Like this image:

https://prnt.sc/x1S0doS7_2H0

For that I am using this code:

```
<b-button type="button" variant="primary" class="float-right" @click="onButtonClick">Open Window Now</b-button>

onButtonClick() {
    window.open(`${this.generatedLink}`, 'popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')
},
```

Now, Once I login I have a callback URL which should return to my main webpage **but currently the callback is return to that window**. I don't want it.

Is there any way to get back to main webpage?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you tell us what is `this.generatedLink`? I think you can set a callback URL if you use google login. And in the callback page, you can close the popup window.

Comment: `this.generatedLink` is generating google login link. Using that link I can show the google login form.